# Is lookup required when adding elements to std::map?

Tags: c++, dictionary, data-structures, lookup, stdmap

<sub>(a natural question from a beginner's perspective, but I couldn't find one. It may be due to my lack of understanding of data structure.)</sub>

Let's assume a situation where there is no need to check if the key already exists when inserting an element into the `std::map`. E.g. Inserting a pair from another std::map(which doesn't have duplicate keys).

But, as far as I know, `operator[]`, `insert`, and `emplace` lookup the key among the existing keys.

Is lookup required, because `std::map` is a tree-type data structure? (although it's up to the implementation).
Since the map must be sorted by key, it seems impossible not to do a lookup when inserting.

Is my understanding correct, or is there a way to add a key (and its mapped value) into `std::map` without checking for duplicates?

Comment: [std::emplace_hint](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace_hint).

Comment: In a balanced tree, finding an existing key happens naturally as a side effect of looking for the right place to insert the new node. It's not something that requires an extra effort.

Comment: You can't determine if something exists in the thing you want to insert into, without checking if it is there. You have to check. How *expensive* it is to check and whether or not it can be done as a side-effect of the insetion process is a different matter.

Comment: "is there a way to add a key (and its mapped value) into std::map without checking for duplicates?" - No. How could you possibly insert something into a container that cannot contain duplicates without checking for the value already being contained? That's simply, logically, not possible. What you are asking for is Magic - not possible in this realm.

Comment: std::map and std::unordered_map are generally bad compromises for nearly every situation and were just made to be backwards compatible when c++ was standardized.   If you care about performance, you almost certainly shouldn't be using either one of them.   So either don't care or use something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is lookup required, because `std::map` is a tree-type data structure?

No, lookup is (practically) required because lookup is required to be faster than O(n). (It is not required that a `std::map` be implemented as a tree-type data structure.)

If lookup was allowed to be O(n), then it would not matter where a new element goes; a search could simply look at everything. Conversely, looking at everything takes O(n) time. In order to beat this time complexity, a search must be able to eliminate some entries from consideration without looking at them.

When adding an element to a `std::map`, the new element must not be placed where the lookup will eliminate it without looking at it. That is, it must be placed so that looking it up will find it. How long does it take to find a place for the new element? Well, if it took less time than finding the element later, replace your "find" algorithm with whatever you use to find a place for the new element. If it takes more time, replace whatever you use to find a place for the new element with your "find" algorithm. The end result is that whatever you use to find a place for the new element is equivalent, in terms of algorithmic complexity, to finding the element later.

So an insertion requires a process that is as complex as lookup. For practical considerations, we might as well say insertion does a lookup. (I'll add the caveat that the lookup could be done in advance of the insertion – with other work done in between – as long as the insertion has the result of the lookup and as long as the "other work" does not invalidate the lookup. The standard containers do not expose such an interface, though.)

---

Note that the above applies to all standard sorted containers, not just `std::map`. I would in particular call out `std::multimap`, where the existence of a duplicate key does not prevent an insertion. (To me, the question reads as if the thought was that the point of performing the lookup was to prevent duplicates.) Even when duplicate keys are allowed, insertion requires a lookup (or equivalent) whenever lookup is required to be faster than O(n).

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure if I understood your answer correctly, but can I assume you're saying something similar to @IgorTandetnik's comment? (sorry for being late!)

Comment: @starriet Igor's comment looks like a special case of this, so yes, it's similar.

Comment: Then, can we generalize and say like this? - "In all _sorted_ containers, finding an existing key happens naturally as a side effect of looking for the right place to insert the new node. It's not something that requires an extra effort."

Comment: @starriet *"can we generalize and say like this?"* -- No, I would not make that claim. It happens in many sorted containers, but I'm not going to claim it for *all* sorted containers. *It's possible that a search might lead to two places to check, where the search has to check both places, but an insertion need only check one. It's still true that insertion has the same time complexity as finding (dividing by 2 does not affect complexity), but it's not guaranteed to be the same as finding.*

Answer (score 3):

A lookup is required (from a conceptual level) for a very simple reason: `std::map` can only hold a single value for a specified key.

Therefore: the rules of logic of our shared universe impose a requirement, in order to determine whether the key already exists, or not, in the map. The requirement is to look it up. There is no alternative.

Now, note that this is referencing what `std::map` must do, when it is given the task of inserting something into itself. There is no requirement for you to manually check if the key exists, or not, in the map, before attempting to `insert()` something into it. You have no obligation to do that. Except that if you don't do that, and the key exists, nothing gets inserted in the map.

Forging ahead on this topic: `insert()` returns a value. Your C++ textbook should have a description of what, specifically, `insert()` returns, and by inspecting the returned value you will discover if the insert really happened, or did not happen because the key already existed.

So, from a different point of view: no, you are not required, in your own code, to check if the key exists before inserting. If you don't, `insert()` will do it for you. In fact, `insert()` will always do it (except that the C++ standard allows your suffering C++ compiler to optimize it away if it is able to logically prove that `insert()` will never find a duplicate key because your code checked for that first, and there are no observable side effects from this optimization, but you can't rely on that of course).